# Failing to open OleDbConnection to Jet database after setting TMP environment variable in the process

Tags: c#, environment-variables, oledbconnection

Earlier in the process, I set the TMP environment variable to a sibling folder of where the Jet database is. I use this code:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TMP", "<sibling to Jet database>");
```

When I call `OleDbConnection.Open()`, I get the error.
Here is the stacktrace:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Unspecified error
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
```

If I set the environment variable in the shell before running the process instead of setting it in code in the process, I don't get the error.

```
set TMP=<sibling to Jet database>
```

Here is my connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\<sibling to TMP>\\database.mdb;
```

I tried to create a sample console application, but it does **not** exhibit the same behavior. There it works. The application where I see the error is a WinForms application with target .NET Framework version set to .NET 4.6.1.

The folder designated in the value of the TMP environment variable **does** exist and permissions are set to full control to everyone.

Even if I set TMP to the same folder in the shell as in code in the process, I still get the error. If I set some other environment variable in code in the process, I do **not** get the error.

**Update:**
If I set the TMP environment variable at the user level, I don't see the error:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TMP", "<sibling to Jet database>", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

Unfortunately that won't work for me as I only want the TMP environment variable to be changed in the scope of the process and not affect other process on the machine.

Comment: Jet only supports Access 2003.  So make sure the database was saved to Access 2003 and not a new version of access.

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for the comment. However, the database is created initially from code using the same connection, so I know it is the correct version. I am not using Access, but rather the support for Jet that is built into the Windows operating system.

Comment: It is still an mdb file. I would open with Access and see if the file is good.  Often files are save with wrong extensions so after writing you cannot read.  The c# code is seeing the file with an mdb extension and then trying to read as an access database.

Comment: @jdweng, I actually don't even have Access installed on my machine, but I know the connection works if I don't set the TMP environment variable in the process. I can open the connection and successfully execute a query.

Comment: See if your computer uses TEMP instead of TMP.  From cmd.exe > Set  : which will give list of environmental variables.

Comment: Both TMP and TEMP are set to the same value.

Comment: Does the folder exist on the PC?  Do you have write permission to folder?

Comment: Yes, the folder exists, and I have full control permissions.

Comment: @jdweng, it actually turns out that the temp folder was indeed deleted by the process itself before the attempt to open the connection. So the cause was that the TMP environment variable was pointing to a folder that does not exist. If you make that the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the error you will get if the TMP environment variable is set to a folder that does not exist.